# What Happens to a Sub Soul when a Soul Reaper reclaims their Gigai?

Tags: bleach

When we see Rukia use Soul Candy to leave her Gigai, the Sub Soul, Chappy, appears to have a very distinct personality.

So when a Soul Reaper leaves their Gigai leaving it to the Sub Soul, what happens to the Sub Soul when they take it back over? do they get ejected like a Mod Soul or are they simply destroyed?